# JPS : HQL query to check null attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have Parcel AND File entities as below

```
@Entity
Parcel{
    Long id;
    String name;
    File file;
}

@Entity
File{
    Long id;
    String name;
    byte[] data; 
}
```

Am trying to get Parcels which has null File reference So I tried the below and which is returning empty list even though I have few parcels with null File reference

```
select p.id from Parcel as p join p.File as f where f is null
```

Can someone help me with this HQL query to get Parcels with null File reference?

Comment: why the join? p can check its value without it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a *left (outer) join*:

```
select p.id from Parcel as p left join p.File as f where f is null
```

Your `join` is an `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

`select p.id from Parcel as p where p.file is null`